# Is there any way to add QSystemTrayIcon via Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

Is there any way to add `QSystemTrayIcon` via Qt Designer, not programmatically?

I don't see it in the list of the controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `QSystemTrayIcon` inherits `QObject` and not `QWidget`.